# HERE API: Clicking project doesn't go to Generate AppID page

Tags: here-api

When I had only one project, clicking it didn't go to the Generate AppID page. Once I added a second project, clicking either of them took me to that page. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: I have only one project on https://developer.here.com/projects, and when I click on it, it takes me to the project detail page where I can generate credentials. Sounds like you had a bug. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: To do that, I'd have to delete at least one project. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This may be one time issue but as of now this is not happening.

https://developer.here.com/projects 
taking to the project page where credentials are generated.
Please do let us know if you still have this issue.